# Finding the MIN value that appears for each unique value in either of two other columns

Tags: mysql

Given the  following (simplified) tables:

People `p`

```
id  name    registered
-----------------------------------
1   Geoff   2011-03-29 12:09:08
2   Phil    2011-04-29 09:03:54
3   Tony    2011-05-29 21:22:23
4   Gary    2011-06-21 22:56:08
...
```

Items `i`

```
date                        p1id    p2id    
----------------------------------------
2011-06-29 20:09:44         1       2
2011-06-26 10:45:00         1       3
2011-06-23 12:22:43         2       3
2011-06-22 13:07:12         2       4
...
```

I'd like: 
    The earliest single `i.date` that each `p.id` appears in *either* column `p1id` or `p2id`; or `p.registered` if they feature in neither.

So far, I've tried:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (id INT);
INSERT INTO temp (id) 
    SELECT DISTINCT u FROM (
        SELECT p1id AS u FROM Items UNION ALL 
        SELECT p2id AS u FROM Items
    )tt;
SELECT registered,id FROM People 
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp);
```

Which gets me as far as the second part, albeit in a fairly clumsy way; and I'm stuck on the first part beyond some sort of external, scripted iteration through all the values of `p.id` (ugh).

Can anyone help?

I'm on MySQL 5.1 and there's ~20k people and ~100k items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution:

```
SELECT id, name, IF(min_date1 IS NULL AND min_date2 IS NULL, registered, LEAST(COALESCE(min_date1, min_date2), COALESCE(min_date2, min_date1))) date FROM (
  SELECT p.id, p.name, p.registered, MIN(i1.date) min_date1, MIN(i2.date) min_date2 FROM people p
    LEFT JOIN items i1
      ON p.id = i1.p1id
    LEFT JOIN items i2
      ON p.id = i2.p2id
  GROUP BY id
) t;
```

OR this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COALESCE(MIN(i.date), p.registered) FROM people p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p1id id, date FROM items
      UNION ALL
    SELECT p2id id, date FROM items
  ) i
  ON p.id = i.id
GROUP BY id;
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | name  | date                |
+------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 | Geoff | 2011-06-26 10:45:00 |
|    2 | Phil  | 2011-06-22 13:07:12 |
|    3 | Tony  | 2011-06-23 12:22:43 |
|    4 | Gary  | 2011-06-22 13:07:12 |
+------+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect! That second one does the trick very nicely. (+1 to Flimzy too, for much the same). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is tested in Postgres, but I think it ought to work in MySQL with few or no changes:

```
SELECT p.id,COALESCE(MIN(x.date),p.registered) AS date
FROM p
JOIN (
    SELECT p.id,MIN(i.date) AS date
    FROM p
    JOIN i ON (p.id=i.p1id)
    GROUP BY p.id
UNION
    SELECT p.id,MIN(i.date) AS date
    FROM p
    JOIN i ON (p.id=i.p2id)
    GROUP BY p.id
) AS x ON x.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id,p.registered;
```

Output (given your sample data):

```
 id |        date         
----+---------------------
  3 | 2011-06-23 12:22:43
  1 | 2011-06-26 10:45:00
  2 | 2011-06-22 13:07:12
  4 | 2011-06-22 13:07:12
(4 rows)
```